# What is the chart lines in google analytics overview display?

Tags: google-analytics

when I look in Google analytics under visitors overview there is a line chart that tell me how many users per day I have had. But these numbers does not add up to the ones below that show users, new users, sessions and so on. What does the line chart actually tell me? If I for example export the report to an excel file by day I get a lot higher number of users per day compared to exporting by month which is much lower. Can someone explain the difference. I wanted to know the number of visits to the site per day....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the trend tells you how many individual users visited the site per day, the "Users" below represents you the de-duplicated count of users who came to the site during the time frame applied.

Example: you visit the same site on 4 separate days during a particular week, the line chart will identify you as a visitor on all 4 days (4 daily users). While the User count below counts you an "one" user for the week.